# Is the usage "an accused " in the following sentence right?

Tags: articles

A news item says, "H C Gupta and five firms have been named as *an accused*". Is it proper to use *an accuse*d when the accused are six six in number in this case?

If the usage *an accuse*d is proper, kindly point out the underlying grammar principle also - for better clarity on the usage.

Comment: Can you please link your quote to the source so as to have more context?

Comment: The author would have done well to write "...have *each* been named as an accused".  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22have%20each%20been%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: @Lucian Sava   The answer  TRomano provided is quite satisfactory, yet  I add the link here. Please see the first line of 4th para   at [link] (http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/special-courts-poser-to-cbi/article7160319.ece)

Comment: TRomano's assertion is fine but the sentence from your link is ungrammatical (IMHO).

Comment: @Lucian Sava Yes,the sentence is ungrammatical and it should have been as TRomano had said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we have more than one entity named as the subject in a (here passive) construction, we use the word *each* to indicate that the verb-phrase applies to the nouns individually and not as a group:

**Moe, Larry, and Curly have *each* been punched in the nose.**

**H C Gupta and five firms have *each* been named as an accused.**

The same is true of active voice constructions; we use *each* to indicate that the subjects individually are doing the thing referred to by the verb-phrase, not acting as one:

**H C Gupta and the five firms are *each* hiring lawyers to represent them.**

That means each company is hiring its own lawyers; they're not sharing lawyers; they're defending themselves individually.